# How do I add multiple draggable area in a Radar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to javascript and english, sorry for bad english.

I have a radar chart created using this  [demo](http://tupel.cl/graficos/ejemplo1/demo.html) code
Now I want to add another area to the same graph, using a button, I am not able to do this.

Please help me.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  // here i want to add another set of daata
  });
$("#btn").click(function(){
  d = [
      {axis: "axisA", value: 2, order:0}, 
      {axis: "axisB", value: 8, order:1},
      {axis: "axisC", value: 4, order:2},
      {axis: "axisD", value: 6, order:3}
 ];

 RadarChart.draw("#chart", d);
 })
 
var RadarChart = {draw: function(id, d, options){
    var cfg = {
radius: 6, w: 600,h: 600,
      factor: 1,

      factorLegend: .85,
      levels: 3,

      maxValue: 0,
      radians: 2 * Math.PI,
      opacityArea: 0.5,
      color: d3.scale.category10()
    };
    if('undefined' !== typeof options){
      for(var i in options){
        if('undefined' !== typeof options[i]){
          cfg[i] = options[i];
        }
      }
    }
 cfg.maxValue = Math.max(cfg.maxValue, d3.max(d.map(function(o){return o.value}))); 
    var allAxis = (d.map(function(i, j){return i.axis}));
    var total = allAxis.length;

    var radius = cfg.factor*Math.min(cfg.w/2, cfg.h/2);


d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();
var g = d3.select(id).append("svg").attr("width", cfg.w).attr("height", cfg.h).append("g");

var tooltip;

drawFrame();
var maxAxisValues = []; 
drawAxis();
var dataValues = [];
reCalculatePoints();

var areagg = initPolygon();
drawPoly();

drawnode();


function drawFrame(){
  for(var j=0; j<cfg.levels; j++){
    var levelFactor = cfg.factor*radius*((j+1)/cfg.levels);
    g.selectAll(".levels").data(allAxis).enter().append("svg:line")
     .attr("x1", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));})
     .attr("y1", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));})
     .attr("x2", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin((i+1)*cfg.radians/total));})
     .attr("y2", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos((i+1)*cfg.radians/total));})
     .attr("class", "line").style("stroke", "grey").style("stroke-width", "0.5px").attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w/2-levelFactor) + ", " + (cfg.h/2-levelFactor) + ")");;
  }
}


function drawAxis(){
  var axis = g.selectAll(".axis").data(allAxis).enter().append("g").attr("class", "axis");

  axis.append("line")
      .attr("x1", cfg.w/2)
      .attr("y1", cfg.h/2)
      .attr("x2", function(j, i){
        maxAxisValues[i] = {x:cfg.w/2*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total)), y:0};
        return maxAxisValues[i].x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(j, i){
        maxAxisValues[i].y = cfg.h/2*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));
        return maxAxisValues[i].y;
      })
      .attr("class", "line").style("stroke", "grey").style("stroke-width", "1px");

  axis.append("text").attr("class", "legend")
      .text(function(d){return d}).style("font-family", "sans-serif").style("font-size", "10px").attr("transform", function(d, i){return "translate(0, -10)";})
      .attr("x", function(d, i){return cfg.w/2*(1-cfg.factorLegend*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total))-20*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total);})
      .attr("y", function(d, i){return cfg.h/2*(1-Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total))+20*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total);});
}

function reCalculatePoints(){
  g.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(d, function(j, i){
      dataValues[i] =
      [
        cfg.w/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total)),
        cfg.h/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total)),
      ];
    });
  dataValues[d[0].length] = dataValues[0];
}

function initPolygon(){
  return g.selectAll("area").data([dataValues])
            .enter()
            .append("polygon")
            .attr("class", "radar-chart-serie0")
            .style("stroke-width", "2px")
            .style("stroke", cfg.color(0))
            .on('mouseover', function (d){
              z = "polygon."+d3.select(this).attr("class");
              g.selectAll("polygon").transition(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.1); 
              g.selectAll(z).transition(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(){
              g.selectAll("polygon").transition(200).style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
            })
            .style("fill", function(j, i){return cfg.color(0);})
            .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
}

function drawPoly(){
  areagg.attr("points",function(de) {
      var str="";
      for(var pti=0;pti<de.length;pti++){
        str=str+de[pti][0]+","+de[pti][1]+" ";
      }            
      return str;
    });
}

function drawnode(){    
  g.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(d).enter()
    .append("svg:circle").attr("class", "radar-chart-serie0")
    .attr('r', cfg.radius)
    .attr("alt", function(j){return Math.max(j.value, 0);})
    .attr("cx", function(j, i){
      return cfg.w/2*(1-(Math.max(j.value, 0)/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));
    })
    .attr("cy", function(j, i){
      return cfg.h/2*(1-(Math.max(j.value, 0)/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));
    })
    .attr("data-id", function(j){return j.axis;})
    .style("fill", cfg.color(0)).style("fill-opacity", 0.9)
    .on('mouseover', function (d){
                newX =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
                newY =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 5;
                tooltip.attr('x', newX).attr('y', newY).text(d.value).transition(200).style('opacity', 1);
                z = "polygon."+d3.select(this).attr("class");
                g.selectAll("polygon").transition(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
                g.selectAll(z).transition(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
              })
    .on('mouseout', function(){
                tooltip.transition(200).style('opacity', 0);
                g.selectAll("polygon").transition(200).style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
              })
    .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", move))      // for drag & drop
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(function(j){return Math.max(j.value, 0)});
}

//Tooltip
tooltip = g.append('text').style('opacity', 0).style('font-family', 'sans-serif').style('font-size', 13);


function move(dobj, i){
  this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  var dragTarget = d3.select(this);

  var oldData = dragTarget.data()[0];

  var oldX = parseFloat(dragTarget.attr("cx")) - 300;
  var oldY = 300 - parseFloat(dragTarget.attr("cy"));
  var newY = 0, newX = 0, newValue = 0;
  var maxX = maxAxisValues[i].x - 300;
  var maxY = 300 - maxAxisValues[i].y;

  if(oldX == 0) {
    newY = oldY - d3.event.dy;

    if(Math.abs(newY) > Math.abs(maxY)) {
      newY = maxY;
    }
    newValue = (newY/oldY) * oldData.value;
  }
  else
  {
    var slope = oldY / oldX;   
    newX = d3.event.dx + parseFloat(dragTarget.attr("cx")) - 300;

    if(Math.abs(newX) > Math.abs(maxX)) {
      newX = maxX;
    }
    newY = newX * slope;

    var ratio = newX / oldX; 
    newValue = ratio * oldData.value;
  }

  dragTarget
      .attr("cx", function(){return newX + 300 ;})
      .attr("cy", function(){return 300 - newY;});

  d[oldData.order].value=newValue;
  reCalculatePoints();
  drawPoly();
}}};
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click to add</button>
<button id="btnB">Click to add Another area</button>
   <div id="chart" >

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <button id="btn">Click to add</button>
    <button id="btnB">Click to add Another area</button>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script>
        d = [
                 {axis: "axisA", value: 2, order:0}, 
                 {axis: "axisB", value: 8, order:1},
                 {axis: "axisC", value: 4, order:2},
                 {axis: "axisD", value: 6, order:3}
            ];

        var RadarChart = {draw: function(id, d, options){
            var cfg = {
        radius: 6, w: 600,h: 600,
              factor: 1,

              factorLegend: .85,
              levels: 3,

              maxValue: 0,
              radians: 2 * Math.PI,
              opacityArea: 0.5,
              color: d3.scale.category10()
            };
            if('undefined' !== typeof options){
              for(var i in options){
                if('undefined' !== typeof options[i]){
                  cfg[i] = options[i];
                }
              }
            }
         cfg.maxValue = Math.max(cfg.maxValue, d3.max(d.map(function(o){return o.value}))); 
            var allAxis = (d.map(function(i, j){return i.axis}));
            var total = allAxis.length;

            var radius = cfg.factor*Math.min(cfg.w/2, cfg.h/2);


        d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();
        var g = d3.select(id).append("svg").attr("width", cfg.w).attr("height", cfg.h).append("g");

        var tooltip;

        drawFrame();
        var maxAxisValues = []; 
        drawAxis();
        var dataValues = [];
        reCalculatePoints();

        var areagg = initPolygon();
        drawPoly();

        drawnode();


        function drawFrame(){
          for(var j=0; j<cfg.levels; j++){
            var levelFactor = cfg.factor*radius*((j+1)/cfg.levels);
            g.selectAll(".levels").data(allAxis).enter().append("svg:line")
             .attr("x1", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));})
             .attr("y1", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));})
             .attr("x2", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin((i+1)*cfg.radians/total));})
             .attr("y2", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos((i+1)*cfg.radians/total));})
             .attr("class", "line").style("stroke", "grey").style("stroke-width", "0.5px").attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w/2-levelFactor) + ", " + (cfg.h/2-levelFactor) + ")");;
          }
        }


        function drawAxis(){
          var axis = g.selectAll(".axis").data(allAxis).enter().append("g").attr("class", "axis");

          axis.append("line")
              .attr("x1", cfg.w/2)
              .attr("y1", cfg.h/2)
              .attr("x2", function(j, i){
                maxAxisValues[i] = {x:cfg.w/2*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total)), y:0};
                return maxAxisValues[i].x;
              })
              .attr("y2", function(j, i){
                maxAxisValues[i].y = cfg.h/2*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));
                return maxAxisValues[i].y;
              })
              .attr("class", "line").style("stroke", "grey").style("stroke-width", "1px");

          axis.append("text").attr("class", "legend")
              .text(function(d){return d}).style("font-family", "sans-serif").style("font-size", "10px").attr("transform", function(d, i){return "translate(0, -10)";})
              .attr("x", function(d, i){return cfg.w/2*(1-cfg.factorLegend*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total))-20*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total);})
              .attr("y", function(d, i){return cfg.h/2*(1-Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total))+20*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total);});
        }

        function reCalculatePoints(){
          g.selectAll(".nodes")
            .data(d, function(j, i){
              dataValues[i] =
              [
                cfg.w/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total)),
                cfg.h/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total)),
              ];
            });
          dataValues[d[0].length] = dataValues[0];
        }

        function initPolygon(){
          return g.selectAll("area").data([dataValues])
                    .enter()
                    .append("polygon")
                    .attr("class", "radar-chart-serie0")
                    .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                    .style("stroke", cfg.color(0))
                    .on('mouseover', function (d){
                      z = "polygon."+d3.select(this).attr("class");
                      g.selectAll("polygon").transition(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.1); 
                      g.selectAll(z).transition(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function(){
                      g.selectAll("polygon").transition(200).style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
                    })
                    .style("fill", function(j, i){return cfg.color(0);})
                    .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
        }

        function drawPoly(){
          areagg.attr("points",function(de) {
              var str="";
              for(var pti=0;pti<de.length;pti++){
                str=str+de[pti][0]+","+de[pti][1]+" ";
              }            
              return str;
            });
        }

        function drawnode(){    
          g.selectAll(".nodes")
            .data(d).enter()
            .append("svg:circle").attr("class", "radar-chart-serie0")
            .attr('r', cfg.radius)
            .attr("alt", function(j){return Math.max(j.value, 0);})
            .attr("cx", function(j, i){
              return cfg.w/2*(1-(Math.max(j.value, 0)/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));
            })
            .attr("cy", function(j, i){
              return cfg.h/2*(1-(Math.max(j.value, 0)/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));
            })
            .attr("data-id", function(j){return j.axis;})
            .style("fill", cfg.color(0)).style("fill-opacity", 0.9)
            .on('mouseover', function (d){
                        newX =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
                        newY =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 5;
                        tooltip.attr('x', newX).attr('y', newY).text(d.value).transition(200).style('opacity', 1);
                        z = "polygon."+d3.select(this).attr("class");
                        g.selectAll("polygon").transition(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
                        g.selectAll(z).transition(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
                      })
            .on('mouseout', function(){
                        tooltip.transition(200).style('opacity', 0);
                        g.selectAll("polygon").transition(200).style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
                      })
            .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", move))      // for drag & drop
            .append("svg:title")
            .text(function(j){return Math.max(j.value, 0)});
        }

        //Tooltip
        tooltip = g.append('text').style('opacity', 0).style('font-family', 'sans-serif').style('font-size', 13);


        function move(dobj, i){
          this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
          var dragTarget = d3.select(this);

          var oldData = dragTarget.data()[0];

          var oldX = parseFloat(dragTarget.attr("cx")) - 300;
          var oldY = 300 - parseFloat(dragTarget.attr("cy"));
          var newY = 0, newX = 0, newValue = 0;
          var maxX = maxAxisValues[i].x - 300;
          var maxY = 300 - maxAxisValues[i].y;

          if(oldX == 0) {
            newY = oldY - d3.event.dy;

            if(Math.abs(newY) > Math.abs(maxY)) {
              newY = maxY;
            }
            newValue = (newY/oldY) * oldData.value;
          }
          else
          {
            var slope = oldY / oldX;   
            newX = d3.event.dx + parseFloat(dragTarget.attr("cx")) - 300;

            if(Math.abs(newX) > Math.abs(maxX)) {
              newX = maxX;
            }
            newY = newX * slope;

            var ratio = newX / oldX; 
            newValue = ratio * oldData.value;
          }

          dragTarget
              .attr("cx", function(){return newX + 300 ;})
              .attr("cy", function(){return 300 - newY;});

          d[oldData.order].value=newValue;
          reCalculatePoints();
          drawPoly();
        }}};

        $("#btnB").click(function(){
          d.push({axis: "axisA", value: 1, order:4}, {axis: "axisB", value: 3, order:5}, {axis: "axisC", value: 5, order:6}, {axis: "axisD", value: 7, order:7})
          RadarChart.draw("#chart", d);
          });
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            RadarChart.draw("#chart", d);
        });
        </script> 
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for attending my question.
I have to show both previous and new dat in the chart, means I need to add another area in to the chart. 
How do I do that, pushing another element to the data>

Something like this..
d.push([
      {axis: "axisA", value: 1, order:4}, 
      {axis: "axisB", value: 3, order:5},
      {axis: "axisC", value: 5, order:6},
      {axis: "axisD", value: 7, order:7}
 ])

Comment: Sorry i am not clear with your question. Do you want to add the data to the existing graph and update the same graph or you want to create a new graph next to the existing graph. Why you are using 2 buttons (Click to add and Click to add Another area)

Comment: I have edited my post, check out. Hope this is what you are looking for. Small explanation on changes. i just moved out the code written inside the button(btn) change event and also the data(d). Calling the function draw, when user clicks on "Click to add" button. Then on click of "Click to add another area" pushing the data which you had mentioned in your comment above and then calling the same draw function.

Comment: Kruthi, thank you very much for spending time here, I saw your code, let me explain a bit more..
I need another set of values to be added to the chart, means 2 set of data with different values, 2 diagram will be shown. In your code you are adding axis. I am not need that sorry.
eg:
 d.push([
      {axis: "axisA", value: 2, order:0}, 
      {axis: "axisB", value: 8, order:1},
      {axis: "axisC", value: 4, order:2},
      {axis: "axisD", value: 6, order:3}
 ])

Comment: As per your example,you are pushing the data to the same dataset, if you want 2 different data set and 2 different diagrams then just replicate the same code with different dataset. Add one more chart to div eg: <div id="chart1" class="container"> and <div id="chart2" class="container"> with .container{float:left}; (CSS ctyle). This will add a new diagram to the window with different dataset and will be placed side by side.

Comment: The code which i have posted does the same. Except pushing the data to same dataset(as you had mentioned in your comment  d.push([ {axis: "axisA", value: 2, order:0}, {axis: "axisB", value: 8, order:1}, {axis: "axisC", value: 4, order:2}, {axis: "axisD", value: 6, order:3} ])). So if you want different dataset then why you want to push the data to same dataset. Use 2 different datasets in the code i have posted it will do your work. And please be clear on your requirement.

Comment: Kruthi, I have explained in image here : http://postimg.org/image/px1nmaznt/
Please have a look

Comment: ok got it.. check this article, you will get an idea on how to add data to the existing graph. http://pothibo.com/2013/09/d3-js-how-to-handle-dynamic-json-data/.

Comment: If you have got the answer then mark the ans as correct